# Open in my app for (xlsx,ppt,pptx.docx) from the safari or mail not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I am using iOS 5.1 sdk for developing my app, but the "Open In" is not working for pptx, ppt, docx, xlsx. Can somebody give me the setting for info.plist? I am using com.microsoft.word.doc, com.microsoft.excel.xls, com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt for the document type.

CFBundleTypeIconFiles CFBundleTypeName Microsoft PowerPoint presentation CFBundleTypeRole Viewer LSHandlerRank Alternate LSItemContentTypes com.microsoft.powerpoint.​ppt com.microsoft.powerpoint.​pptx CFBundleTypeIconFiles CFBundleTypeName Excel Document CFBundleTypeRole Viewer LSHandlerRank Alternate LSItemContentTypes com.microsoft.excel.xls com.microsoft.excel.xlsx

Comment: Show the complete `Document types` entry from your Info.plist.

Comment: maddy u can refer the above code where i mentioned the UTI types.

Comment: Can you take a moment to format that text so it's readable? A little indenting and line wrapping will go a long way.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> NSArray *extensionArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"doc", @"docx", @"ppt", @"pptx", @"xls", @"xlsx",@"mp3",@"mp4",@"rft",@"rtf",@"pages",@"key",@"numbers",nil];
>
>    for (int i=0; i<[extensionArray count]; i++) {
>        NSString *fileExtension = [extensionArray objectAtIndex:i];
>        NSString *utiString = (__bridge NSString *)UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,(__bridge CFStringRef)fileExtension,NULL);
>        NSLog(@"Extension: %@ UTI:%@",fileExtension,utiString);
>    }
> ```

We can use this code to print the proper UTI.

Comment: For fellow readers: Pages has an additional UTI of "com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages". Details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56429844/1691231