# Unable to pick pages file with UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I'm using UIDocumentPickerViewController for picking document. Below are the specified UTIs :

```
NSArray *types = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeImage,(NSString*)kUTTypeSpreadsheet,(NSString*)kUTTypePresentation,(NSString*)kUTTypePDF,(NSString*)kUTTypeRTF,(NSString*)kUTTypePlainText,(NSString*)kUTTypeText];

UIDocumentPickerViewController *dpvc = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:types inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```

The files created from pages app (pages file) are grayed out and unable to pick. But WhatsApp document picker allowed to pick the same files. Am I missing any required UTI ?

**My App :**

[image]

**WhatsApp:**

[image]

**UPDATE**

com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages did the trick for pages files on my device, but not working for the files on icloud drive. The complete code to present document picker is:

```
-(IBAction)showDocumentPicker:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *types = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeImage,(NSString*)kUTTypeSpreadsheet,(NSString*)kUTTypePresentation,(NSString*)kUTTypePDF,(NSString*)kUTTypeRTF,(NSString*)kUTTypePlainText,(NSString*)kUTTypeText, @"com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages"];

    UIDocumentPickerViewController *dpvc = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:types inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];

    dpvc.delegate = self;

    //colorFromHex 4285f4
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:66.0/255.0 green:133.0/255.0 blue:244.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    [self presentViewController:dpvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand you need all composite content formats and these are all of them kUTTypePDF, kUTTypeRTFD, kUTTypeFlatRTFD, kUTTypeTXNTextAndMultimediaData, kUTTypeWebArchive.

Comment: @m1sh0 Thanks, but none of these are working :(

Comment: did you try with these once "com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", "com.apple.iwork.keynote.key" ???

Comment: @m1sh0 Yes, posted a question after tried that.

Comment: @m1sh0 I had to clean build after specifying these UTIs. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there are 2 different types for Pages files, it could be a bundle or a single file, and I think that you want your app to handle both.

The corresponding UTIs are `com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages` and `com.apple.iwork.pages.pages`.

Example of code to import iWork files:

```
NSArray *types = @[@"com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages", @"com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", @"com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", @"com.apple.iwork.keynote.key"];

UIDocumentPickerViewController *dpvc = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:types inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```

I also recommand that you watch this WWDC session if you still have trouble with `UIDocumentPickerViewController`: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/216

Comment: com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages did the trick, but now pages **on my device** only can access. When the same pages file copied the  to **icloud drive**, its unaccessible.

Comment: However the numbers and keynote file on icloud drive are accessible, the pages not.

Comment: Please have a look at my update in the question. @TheFlow

Comment: @iAkki I updated my answer with an example code, could you try it?

Comment: Fixed! I don't know why its always requiring me to clean project after changing the types. I forgot  to clean last time when specified both .sffpages and .pages UTIs. Now its working. Many thanks for your help :) @TheFlow